# how to highlight two same days in a week in javascript with the same string

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to write the javascript once for all without having to change the string names over and over again, changing the string name basically. one string name works for all. i will be having different weekes calendars  for different stores more then two in the same page. i would like to keep it as less code as possible or would i have to change the string names

```js
var now = new Date();
var days = ['Sunday02', 'Monday02', 'Tuesday02', 'Wednesday02', 'Thursday02', 'Friday02', 'Saturday02'];

var today = days[now.getDay()]; //code to assign todays day to variable
document.getElementById(today).style.background = '#FFFF00';

//$("#"+today).addClass("highlight"); //Jquery


var now = new Date();
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

var today = days[now.getDay()]; //code to assign todays day to variable
document.getElementById(today).style.background = '#FFFF00';

//$("#"+today).addClass("highlight"); //Jquery
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<h2>We're Open At These Times Store 1</h2>
<div id="Monday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Monday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 10pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Tuesday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 10pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Wednesday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 10pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Thursday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Thursday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 10pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Friday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Friday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 11pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Saturday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Saturday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 11pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Sunday" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Sunday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 10pm</div>
</div>


<h2>We're Open At These Times Store 2</h2>
<div id="Monday02" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Monday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 10pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Tuesday02" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 10pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Wednesday02" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 10pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Thursday02" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Thursday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 10pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Friday02" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Friday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 11pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Saturday02" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Saturday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 11pm</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="Sunday02" class="dateTime">
  <div class="day">Sunday</div>
  <div class="time">10am - 10pm</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do they all have the same open hours ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your stores and schedule inside an array (`stores`). The rest of the code will automatically display the stores and schedule that are inside this array. If you need another store, you add it to the array and keep the rest of the code.

The code will first iterate the array to create the DOM element to insert inside the `<div>`

The second part will find the elements with the class of the current day and will add the class `highlight`

```js
const stores = [{
  name: 'Store A',
  schedule: {
    monday: '10am - 10pm',
    tuesday: '10am - 10pm',
    wednesday: '10am - 10pm',
    thursday: '10am - 10pm',
    friday: '10am - 11pm',
    saturday: '10am - 11pm',
    sunday: '10am - 11pm'
  }
}, {
  name: 'Store B',
  schedule: {
    monday: '10am - 10pm',
    tuesday: '10am - 10pm',
    wednesday: '10am - 10pm',
    thursday: '10am - 10pm',
    friday: '10am - 11pm',
    saturday: '10am - 11pm',
    sunday: '10am - 11pm'
  }
}];
//Display the schedule for each stores
let content = document.getElementById("content");
let html = "";
stores.forEach(s => {
  html += `<h2>We're open at these times : ${s.name}</h2>`;
  for(let k in s.schedule){
    html += `<div class="${k}"><div class="day">${k.toUpperCase()}</div><div class="time">${s.schedule[k]}</div></div><br>`;
  }
});
content.innerHTML = html;

//Highlight today hours
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
const now = new Date();
const dayName = days[now.getDay()].toLowerCase();;
let daysToHighlight = document.getElementsByClassName(dayName);

for(let i=0; i<daysToHighlight.length; i++){
  daysToHighlight[i].className += ' highlight';
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: @AngelRamirez This was linked to firefox and the support for es2015. Snippet is now fixed